# Pass Parameter to custom Android widget

Tags: java, android, widget

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a custom widget? I basically require different text to be displayed in certain situations and dont really want to just copy and paste the whole code. Here is what I have so far for payment_example.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/receipt_layout">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/payment_label"
       android:text="@string/payment_label"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I would require a different text to be displayed in the TextView - android:text field. From the Java side it calls this widget like this:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
final View printLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_example, mainLayout, false);
```

So my question is, is it possible to influence the text that is displayed in this widget?

Comment: I don't get it. Which is the custom widget? TextView isn't a custom widget.

Comment: The payment_example.xml is basically a custom Textbox (with some other stuff which i've stripped out)

Comment: does printLayout.findViewById(R.id.payment_label).setText("text"); work ?

Comment: "The method setText(String) is undefined for the type View"

Comment: Well cast it to a TextView, TextView t = (TextView)printLayout.findViewById(R.id.payment_label); t.setText("test");

Comment: After some playing around I managed to get this working - thanks